# Convert text to links - ignore image src

Tags: php, regex

I am using the following function to convert text links to active links:

```
    function makeClickableLinks($text) {
    $text = eregi_replace('(((f|ht){1}tp://)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]+)','<a href="\\1">\\1</a>', $text);
    $text = eregi_replace('([[:space:]()[{}])(www.[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]+)','\\1<a href="http://\\2">\\2</a>', $text);
    $text = eregi_replace('([_\.0-9a-z-]+@([0-9a-z][0-9a-z-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,3})','<a href="mailto:\\1">\\1</a>', $text);
    return $text;
    }
```

This works fine, but in case an image has been posted (img src="http://www.yyy.com/zz.gif") the above code will also try to convert the src of the img - with no great result!

How do I avoid the function to convert the src of the img tag?

**I've found a solution:**

```
$text = preg_replace('/(?<!http:\/\/|https:\/\/|\"|=|\'|\'>|\">)(www\..*?)(\s|\Z|\.\Z|\.\s|\<|\>|,)/i',"<a href=\"http://$1\">$1</a>$2",$text);
$text = preg_replace('/(?<!\"|=|\'|\'>|\">|site:)(https?:\/\/(www){0,1}.*?)(\s|\Z|\.\Z|\.\s|\<|\>|,)/i',"<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>$3",$text);
echo "$text";
```

Comment: Note that `ereg_*` family of functions is deprecated. You should use `preg_*` family instead.

Comment: thanks - apparently an old script I am using :)

Comment: @zvinx, if your solution works then post it as an answer!

Comment: @zvinx If your solution is negative look behinds, perhaps you should change "I've found a solution" to "bozdoz found a solution". :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use a negative look behind:

```
(?<!src=")
```

That should exclude URLs in img tags:

```
$text = preg_replace('#(?<!src=")(((f|ht){1}tp://)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~\#?&//=]+)#','<a href="\\1">\\1</a>', $text);
```